# What is the right way to transfer leads from a website to a local CRM?

Tags: php

I have a website with a form which allows a visitor to submit their name, phone, email etc.  This website is hosted at a website hosting company.

I also have a CRM system for managing leads.  This resides locally in my office.  I programmed this CRM system.

When a visitor enters their name, phone etc on the public website, ideally I would like that lead data to be transferred ***instantly*** into my local CRM system.

My question is what is the most professional way to do this?

Option 1: One option is have the website form produce a text file of the lead on the website.  The local CRM could have a cron job running every minute to FTP up, retrieve leads, and import them into the CRM.  But this would not be instant.

Option 2: Another option is to have the website form post directly into the local CRM like this:

```
form action="http://www.{IP ADDRESS OF LOCAL CRM}/signup-thankyou.php"
```

What is the best way to do this?  I am the author of the CRM system, and I am a PHP programmer so I should be able to program whatever is the recommended solution.

Thank you.

Comment: I'd say that totally depends on the product used and what import options it provides.... Option 2 is a bad idea because that opens up your CRM to the public Internet. Do you really *need* it to be instant as in, one minute is too long?

Comment: I am the author of the CRM system, and I am a PHP programmer so I should be able to program whatever is the recommended solution.

Answer (score 0):

your CRM could connect to the remote DB where your site lives

or

you could do a server-side POST request from the signup script, see [cURL function reference](http://lv.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Comment: >>your CRM could connect to the remote DB where your site lives

Comment: >>your CRM could connect to the remote DB where your site lives
in what way?

>>you could do a server-side POST request
do you mean like my option #2?

>>see cURL function reference.
which function?

Comment: >>your CRM could connect to the remote DB where your site lives <br>

in what way?


>>you could do a server-side POST request <br>

do you mean like my option #2? 


>>see cURL function reference. <br>

which function?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Pekka that *option 2* is bad as it publicizes the existence of your CRM server. Instead i would have it send the data from the public server to the CRM server directly, once the form is submited and processed. This way you can lock the CRM server down to only taking connections from the public webserver and move this activity to a non standard port.

Comment: >>send the data from the public server to the CRM server directly.


in what way?

Comment: use cURL to make a POST request as andr mentioned